# Lots of kernels not being removed by Bikeshed

Tags: 14.04, kernel, lts, azure

I've got an Azure based Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server I ran purge-old-kernels (bikeshed) and it said just 1 kernel was eligible for removal. So I let it remove that one.

Then I did a check for all kernels on the system and my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS lists about 28 `linux-image-x.x.x-generic` files, a similar number of `linux-image-extra-x.x.x-generic` and a couple of virtuals.

Any idea why these numerous other kernels aren't being removed?

Is it safe to remove these other kernels?

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic        3.13.0-48.80                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic        3.13.0-49.83                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic        3.13.0-51.84                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic        3.13.0-52.86                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic        3.13.0-53.89                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic        3.13.0-54.91                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic        3.13.0-55.94                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic        3.13.0-57.95                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic        3.13.0-58.97                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic        3.13.0-59.98                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic        3.13.0-61.100                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic        3.13.0-62.102                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic        3.13.0-63.103                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic        3.13.0-65.106                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic        3.13.0-66.108                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic        3.13.0-67.110                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic        3.13.0-68.111                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-71-generic        3.13.0-71.114                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-73-generic        3.13.0-73.116                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic        3.13.0-74.118                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-76-generic        3.13.0-76.120                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-77-generic        3.13.0-77.121                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic        3.13.0-79.123                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic        3.13.0-83.127                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-85-generic        3.13.0-85.129                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-86-generic        3.13.0-86.131                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-87-generic        3.13.0-87.133                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-88-generic        3.13.0-88.135                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-91-generic        3.13.0-91.138                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.2.0-77-virtual         3.2.0-77.112                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 Virtual Guests
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic  3.13.0-48.80                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic  3.13.0-49.83                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-51-generic  3.13.0-51.84                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic  3.13.0-52.86                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic  3.13.0-53.89                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-54-generic  3.13.0-54.91                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic  3.13.0-55.94                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic  3.13.0-57.95                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic  3.13.0-58.97                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-59-generic  3.13.0-59.98                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-61-generic  3.13.0-61.100                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic  3.13.0-62.102                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic  3.13.0-63.103                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic  3.13.0-65.106                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-66-generic  3.13.0-66.108                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-67-generic  3.13.0-67.110                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic  3.13.0-68.111                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-71-generic  3.13.0-71.114                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-73-generic  3.13.0-73.116                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic  3.13.0-74.118                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic  3.13.0-76.120                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic  3.13.0-77.121                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic  3.13.0-79.123                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-83-generic  3.13.0-83.127                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-85-generic  3.13.0-85.129                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-86-generic  3.13.0-86.131                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-87-generic  3.13.0-87.133                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-88-generic  3.13.0-88.135                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-91-generic  3.13.0-91.138                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-virtual            3.13.0.91.97                         amd64        Transitional package.
ii  linux-image-generic                  3.13.0.91.97                         amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-virtual                  3.13.0.91.97                         amd64        This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel image.
```

Comment: Why not run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove these old kernels?

Comment: I did, but that doesn't remove them either.

Comment: what kernel do you see being used after running `uname -r` ?

Comment: 3.13.0-91-generic

Comment: I d say it's safe to remove all but the last 2 or 3 (since your machine already loads the latest one). It is notable though that autoremove doesn't delete them automatically. Maybe because it's a VM? Also check [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/563483/why-doesnt-apt-get-autoremove-remove-my-old-kernels).

Comment: I'm fairly newb to Ubuntu/Linux.... how likely is it that these other kernels are needed / in use? Can a system use more than one kernel?

Comment: I've removed a number of linux-image-x.x.x-generic's. Is it ok to remove the corresponding linux-image-extra-x.x.x-generic's? What are these exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem now, too. So I took the numbers in /boot manually into my command:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove linux-image-3.13.0-{24,85,{88..96}}-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-{24,85,{88..96}}-generic
```

But your dpkg listing shows mostly "rc" which are deleted kernels. But their configuration is kept. This is normally good but not on (so many) kernels. It happens when you use autoremove without --purge.

You could remove them afterwards with the above command (without headers if deinstalled yet) and the corresponding numbers. But it is not so important to do that. But the headers take very much space and file inodes, too.

Answer (score 0):

All kernels marked `rc` are not installed.

I see no problems. Two  kernels `3.13.0-91` and `3.13.0-88` are installed.