# Which kernel version to delete when low disk space on /boot?

Tags: boot, updates

Running on Ubuntu 20.04, low disk space on /boot error message came up while trying to update.

```bash
The upgrade needs a total of 228 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 24,8 M of disk space on '/boot'.
```

in my /boot folder I have the following files:

```bash
/boot
total 460452
drwx------ 3 root root      4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    184884 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    184380 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    182704 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.bin
drwx------ 2 root root     16384 Feb  2  2021 lost+found
-rw------- 1 root root   6219821 Jan  6 17:21 System.map-5.15.0-58-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    262181 Jan  6 17:21 config-5.15.0-58-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  11450528 Jan  6 17:21 vmlinuz-5.15.0-58-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 217500477 Jan 20 06:33 initrd.img-5.15.0-58-generic
-rw------- 1 root root   6221223 Jan 25 10:27 System.map-5.15.0-60-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    262215 Jan 25 10:27 config-5.15.0-60-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  11458344 Jan 25 10:29 vmlinuz-5.15.0-60-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        25 Feb  9 06:53 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-58-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        25 Feb  9 06:53 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-60-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        28 Feb  9 06:53 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.15.0-58-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        28 Feb  9 06:53 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.15.0-60-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 217514515 Feb  9 06:53 initrd.img-5.15.0-60-generic
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root      4096 Feb  9 06:54 grub
```

the command "uname -a" returns:

```bash
uname -a
Linux balazskocsis 5.15.0-60-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 25 09:41:30 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

when I list out the dpkg packages I get:

```bash
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'
linux-generic-hwe-20.04
linux-headers-5.15.0-58-generic
linux-headers-5.8.0-63-generic
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-58
linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-63
linux-image-5.15.0-58-generic
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
linux-libc-dev:amd64
linux-modules-5.15.0-58-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-58-generic
```

I believe that I need to clean up with the purge command the kernel version 5-15.0-58:

```bash
sudo apt-get -y purge linux-modules-5.15.0-58-generic
```

but I am not really sure.

If I interpret this correctly:

```bash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        25 Feb  9 06:53 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-58-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        25 Feb  9 06:53 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-60-generic
```

the current version is the 5.15.0-60 and the ones with 5.15.0-58 can be removed.

Given the output of the /boot folder listing and the uname -a, would it be safe to remove the 5.15.0-58 version?

Comment: How much space is in your `/boot`? It seems you have created a bottleneck for yourself by restricting the space in `/boot`. A default Ubuntu installation share `/boot` with `/` so it doesn't run out of space. Also, you have the two latest kernels, which is also the default for Ubuntu (this is a safeguard so you can boot a previous kernel). To avoid problems, have at least 2GB space in `/boot`.

Comment: Older versions of the installer did make `/boot` separate and too small, in some instances. If you've upgraded a machine through a few releases, it's entirely plausible to have a small `/boot` by default.

Comment: I believe the solution is to take some good backups, and then try and resize your partitions - see below..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resize my /boot partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280211/how-do-i-resize-my-boot-partition)

Comment: `purge` seems misused -- there are no files in /etc to remove. The use of `-y` with any `remove` or `purge` command is unwise -- you are telling apt that it's okay to destroy your system without double-checking with you first.

Comment: hi @Arthur Meinid, yes, I have this version for years now, and updated regularly. The boot size is the nominal 1GB, which is currently 71% full. The updates need only extra 28MB more of the free space for the installation. 
The resize of the boot is a good advice, but currently I am reluctant for such solution. Removing old kernels is much more appealing. I just wanted to know if one of those kernel versions (old) is safe to purge.

Comment: @user535733 re: the use of `--purge` for kernels, please [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406581/why-does-ubuntu-not-clean-out-old-kernel-module-files-in-lib-modules-when-old). Old kernels leave a good amount of module files left (up to 3-4 MB per old kernel) if `--purge` is not used - just FYI.

Comment: @ArturMeinild, consider raising the /lib/modules issue in Discourse -- it might be an unreported bug; I've never seen any developer traffic about it. Thanks for enlightening.

Comment: @user535733 I'll look into it. Thanks! 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure that the kernel version 5.15.0-60 is working properly, then yes you can remove kernel version 5-15.0-58.

On my system, the following files are automatically removed for old kernels:

```
linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-xx-generic
linux-modules-5.15.0-xx-generic
linux-image-5.15.0-xx-generic
linux-headers-5.15.0-xx-generic
linux-headers-5.15.0-xx
```

So you could run:

```
sudo apt remove --purge linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-58-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-58-generic linux-image-5.15.0-58-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-58-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-58
```

*However, be advised that by doing this, you're **removing the safety net** of having a backup kernel installed (the previous one), and will only have **one working kernel** on the system.*

In the long run, it would be much more advisable to expand your `/boot` partition, so Ubuntu can run normally with 2 working kernels installed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So in case one would have temporarily only one kernel, would a new kernel version by added after an update or an upgrade? i.e. when would a new kernel version come out, so a new "safety-net" could be generated?

Comment: Yes. But this situation would likely repeat itself, in that each time a new kernel was released, you first had to remove the previous one before you could upgrade. But it's perfectly possible to do.