# Every time my system updates it reinstalls a much older kernel, why?

Tags: boot, kernel, updates, 22.04

Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop

Whenever my system updates it always reinstalls an older kernel. This stops the update because of insufficient space on /boot.

Also apt autoremove does not remove my outdated kernels

My curent /boot kernel files look like this:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 6.0M Sep  5 16:31 System.map-5.15.0-84-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 7.6M Aug 18 12:38 System.map-6.2.0-32-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 7.7M Sep  7 10:11 System.map-6.2.0-33-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Sep 19 11:04 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-84-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  12M Sep  5 19:57 vmlinuz-5.15.0-84-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  14M Aug 18 12:40 vmlinuz-6.2.0-32-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  14M Sep  7 11:18 vmlinuz-6.2.0-33-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Sep 19 11:04 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-6.2.0-33-generic
```

I noticed that there are some earlier kernels marked as manual in apt. I switched them to auto and redid purge but 5.15 is still there.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have both GA & HWE kernel stacks installed; if so you'd expect to see 5.15 (GA) + 6.2 (HWE); with both being updated with security fixes.

Comment: No - only HWE as far as I know - certainly never asked for GA, and my hardware is very vanilla

Comment: Which kernel stack is installed by default varies on the ISO used to install (*you didn't specify your product/flavor of 22.04 thus we cannot even know what is likely*). You could try viewing what package(s) you have installed using `dpkg -l |grep linux-generic` but 5.15 will get re-install if either GA kernel stack was installed; OR you'd previously installed a 5.15 kernel. Ubuntu allows users to install multiple kernel stacks (*and all will get upgrades if supported*)

Comment: dpkg -l |grep linux-generic returns nothing.My product flavor is pure Ubuntu - not one of the other flavors.

Comment: Classic apt misuse of "purge". Purge is not a synonym for "force". They do very different things, and neither seem necessary for the problem as currently described.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1486305/edit) to clarify: Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 or Ubuntu Server 22.04?

Comment: Also please edit your question to show the complete output of `sudo apt autoremove linux-image-5.15.0-84-generic`. Read the output before agreeing to any removals. Reject the removal if the output says something unexpected.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` please.

Comment: I booted a *jammy* or 22.04 system, and my own results for command I provided show both `linux-image-generic` and `linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04`  plus various kernel packages installed; I'd not expect no results (there is no mention of OEM kernels in your directory listing).  Ubuntu or Ubuntu *flavor* are still Ubuntu systems (*you didn't specify Desktop or Server, but they'll be the same; I used a desktop system*)

Comment: sudo apt autoremove linux-image-5.15.0-84-generic shows 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  amd64-microcode intel-microcode iucode-tool linux-image-5.15.0-84-generic linux-image-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-84-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-84-generic thermald

but I've already done that, removed the package and then it was reinstalled on the next kernel update.

I modified the original question to include the fact that it is a desktop system.

Comment: I found a partial answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/563483/why-doesnt-apt-get-autoremove-remove-my-old-kernels#563489  - it seems that autoremove will never remove a kernel unhttps://askubuntu.com/questions/563483/why-doesnt-apt-get-autoremove-remove-my-old-kernels#563489less it is specifcied - ok, I get that, but why is it reinstalling to (much) older kernel?

Comment: Autoremove will remove kernels. You are almost certainly getting this issue because you have the HWE and 'base' kernel packages both installed. To fix it, do this https://askubuntu.com/a/885582/243321